# Speeding up xqueries containing DOM objects

Tags: dom, xquery, saxon

We are currently using DOM objects in our code to run xqueries. The aim is to shift to TinyTree,to improve performance of queries, however a large amount of time is taken to convert a dom to tiny tree before calling saxon xquery evaluator. This reduces the performance improvement obtained due to shift of the model. Can there be anything else done, apart from converting a DOM to TinyTree prior to calling saxon library to improve xquery performance, on the following lines

1. Is is possible to write an xquery such that the dom is first converted to tinytree and then the rest of the query happens? Would that give a better performance than conversion to TinyTree outside saxon?
2. Any other DOM based model that would have a better speed than the standard DOM?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "DOM based". Certainly, XOM performs rather better with Saxon than DOM does.

Did you find this article? https://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2012/09/comparing-dom-and-other-object-models.html -- it's quite old, but still relevant.

One thing that's come on the scene since then is the Domino model, which is basically using a DOM with added indexes. See https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/#!sourcedocs/tree-models/domino

How are you converting DOM to TinyTree? There may be a faster way than you are using. At the s9api level, the best way is probably to create a `net.sf.saxon.s9api.DocumentBuilder` and call `build(Source)`, supplying a `DOMSource`. If you need to do it within XPath or XQuery, use the `fn:copy-of()` function.